# Order of enumeration?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have this simple (test) table :

[image]

- `namee` is a worker name
- `salaryStep` is a date which represents a new raised salary date.

I need to find in which step I'm currently on. ( based on a given date)

For example if the given date is `2013 nov 11` then I should be at `id=2`.

So the logic is pretty simple :

1) sort the table via `salarystep DESC`

2) from that , take the first item which is smaller then `@now`

But when I implemented it via

```
DECLARE @now date = '20131111'
SELECT    TOP 1  salaryStep
FROM   (
           SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
                  salaryStep
           FROM   [aaa].[dbo].[Table_1]
           ORDER BY
                  salaryStep DESC
       )         a
WHERE  a.salaryStep<=@now
```

The answer was :

`2013-10-02` --incorrect

And so I ask :

**Question #1**

It seems that *although* I specified in the inner select :  `order by salaryStep DESC` , the enumeration does start at that order . why is that ?

**Question #2**

What is the correct way of doing it ?

Required result :

`2013-10-15` ( or id=2 , nevermind)

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?  And just do simple one-column  SELECT SALARYSTEP FROM tABLE_1 ORDER salarystep DESC

Comment: @Leptonator id is clustered identity seed

Comment: see my amendment please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be enough:

```
DECLARE @now date = '20131111'
SELECT    TOP 1  salaryStep
FROM [aaa].[dbo].[Table_1]
WHERE  salaryStep<=@now
ORDER BY salaryStep DESC
```

And the answer to your question #1 is that it doesn't matter what order your inner query is in, what matters is the outer's query order as `TOP 1` will be impacted by that.

A simple test:

```
create table test(a int)
insert into test values (1)
insert into test values (2)
insert into test values (3)

select top 1 * from
(select top 100 percent a from test order by a desc) x
```

This returns 1 (regardless of the internal ordering when you use `TOP 100 PERCENT`).

Comment: can you please answer the first question ?

Comment: How you can be sure that your query will return '2013-10-15'? Even date '2013-10-02' is smaller then your @now date...

Comment: @veljasije that's becuase `where` is executed first , then select , then order by , then top

Comment: @veljasije and to be more pedant : `1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10 ORDER BY
11. TOP
`

Comment: My mistake, I didn't see TOP 1 :)

Comment: @Szymon Still , it make sense that the outer query should respect the inner sort order..... I still dont get this. the outside `where` cuts the unrelevant rows , so I should be left with **relevant sorted** from which i take top 1...

Comment: Well, it doesn't work this way in SQL Server. Try to remove `TOP` from the inner query. You'll get an error: `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.` Clearly, they didn't want it to work this way.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - "the outer query should respect the inner sort order" - but the only *defined* purpose of the inner `ORDER BY` is to define which rows are selected via the inner `TOP`. There's no actual requirement for the server to perform *any* sorting, so long as the correct columns can be returned that match the `TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY` combination. Since you've asked for 100%, the server knows that it can just return all rows - it's just saved itself some sorting effort.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Are you saying that the inner query is not actually sorted becuase of the 100% ? (_the server knows that it can just return all rows - it's just saved itself some sorting effort._)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever But running the inner query as standalone query does show me the correcet ordered results ( sorry if i dont get what you're saying)

Comment: @RoyiNamir - `ORDER BY` has *two* purposes - to help to define some other feature (such as what `TOP 5` means) and to sort results. This second purpose (sorting results) only applies when the `ORDER BY` is part of the outermost `SELECT` statement. At all other times, its only defined purpose is for assisting with the definition of other features - there is *no* requirement that any actual sorting occurs, and even if sorting does occur, there's no guarantee that the server won't rearrange the rows if that improves its processing elsewhere.